# What is the difference between set complete+=t and set complete+=k in vim?

Tags: autocompletion

In [this wikia tip](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Dictionary_completions) I found `set complete+=k` and `set complete+=t`. I applied both but only the first one worked.

My question is what is the difference between these?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [`:h 'complete'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27complete%27):

```
k   scan the files given with the 'dictionary' option
]   tag completion
t   same as "]"
```

The tag `k` allows you to specify a file containing some words you want to use for completion. The tag `t` is used to complete tags generated by a program like exuberant Ctags or cscope. For more details about tags see [`:h tag`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/tagsrch.txt.html#tag).

When you used `set complete+=t` it's not that it didn't work it is that you probably didn't generate a tag file.